# Date can't show Using Postgre's Row Date to show JqPlot Date Axes

Tags: javascript, jquery, postgresql, sails.js, jqplot

So I have this **model** from sails.js :

```
var sql = 'SELECT TO_DATE(CAST(LAST_UPDATE AS TEXT),\'YYYY-MM-DD\') AS VIEW_DATE, COUNT(STATISTIK_ID) AS VIEW_COUNT \
    FROM STATISTIK \
    GROUP BY VIEW_DATE \
    ORDER BY VIEW_DATE ASC';

    sails.log.debug('Query : ' + sql);

    AdsStatistics.query(sql, function(err, data){
        if(err){
            response({"status": "ERR", "message": err['message']});
        }
        else{
            console.log(data.rows);
            response({"status": "OK", "message": "", "data": data.rows});
        }
    });
```

and this **javascript** on view.ejs

```
var data = response.data;
var iLen = data.length;
var lineData = [];
var line1=[];
var tempDate = new Date();
for (var i = 0; i < iLen; i++){
    tempDate = data[i].view_date;
    lineData[i] = "'"+ tempDate.substring(0,10) + "'," + data[i].view_count;
}
line1 = [lineData];
alert(line1); //just to check the data i parsed
console.log(line1); //just to check the data i parsed
var plot2 = $.jqplot('chart1', [line1] , {
            title:'Views Statistics',
            axes: {
            xaxis: {
                label: 'Date',
                labelRenderer: $.jqplot.CanvasAxisLabelRenderer,
                renderer: $.jqplot.DateAxisRenderer,
                tickOptions: {formatString:'%#d %b %Y'}
            },
            yaxis:{
                label: 'Views',
                labelRenderer: $.jqplot.CanvasAxisLabelRenderer
            }
        },
        series:[{lineWidth:2, markerOptions:{style:'filledCircle'}}]
    });
```

I have the parsed data right already, this is from the console log :

[console log cmd](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CV4xU.png)

and this from the web console :

[web console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6w6mN.png)

but why I still don't get the graph correct ? and I also seems that the jqplot doesn't recognize my date on xaxis. Please help what did I do wrong ?

Answer (score 0):

I turns out that I only have to make a 2 dimensional array for the graph axis data. So I edited my javascript code like this and it works perfectly :

```
var data = response.data;
var iLen = data.length;
var lineData = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < iLen; i++) {
        lineData[i] = [];
        for(var j = 0; j < 2; j++) {
            if(j == 0)
                lineData[i][j] = data[i].view_date.substring(0,10);
            else
                lineData[i][j] = parseInt(data[i].view_count);
        }
    }
    var plot2 = $.jqplot('chart1', [lineData] , {
        title:'Views Statistics',
        axes: {
            xaxis: {
            label: 'Date',
            labelRenderer: $.jqplot.CanvasAxisLabelRenderer,
            renderer: $.jqplot.DateAxisRenderer,
            tickOptions: {formatString:'%#d %b %Y'}
        },
        yaxis:{
            label: 'Views',
            labelRenderer: $.jqplot.CanvasAxisLabelRenderer
        }
    },        series:[{lineWidth:2, markerOptions:{style:'filledCircle'}}]
});
```